# Dragging/dropping or pasting an image in rich text mode results in the image uploader showing the same image twice

Tags: bug, images, uploader, stacks-editor

Dragging/dropping or pasting an image (into the new Stacks Editor) in rich text mode results in the same image being shown twice (side-by-side) in the image uploader:

[image: An image being dropped into the editor and resulting in two side by side images]

Steps to reproduce:

1. Switch to rich text mode.
2. Click inside the editor to activate it (you should see a blue border around the editor).<sup>1</sup>
3. Drag and drop, or paste, an image into the editor.
4. You should see that image being shown twice (side-by-side) in the image uploader.

Note: As intended, clicking on "Add image" will result in a single picture being uploaded.

<sup>1</sup> In the GIF above, I've also shown an example of when the editor has not been activated before dragging/dropping an image. As intended, only a single image is shown in the image uploader.

---

I'm using Chrome (latest version) on Windows 11.
([Bug report opened on GitHub](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/213))

Comment: Please let me know if anyone else can reproduce this issue.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce.

Comment: @CaveJohnson: Could you provide a GIF?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxTsS.gif

Comment: Btw you didn't say in words but based on your gif it looks like it works correctly the first time, but when you click cancel then try again, that's when the image gets duplicated. Is that right?

Comment: @CaveJohnson: You need to click inside the editor to activate it (you'll see a blue border around the editor), *then* drag and drop the image.

Comment: aha I thought you meant opted in to the beta. I'll try again a bit later.

Comment: I could reproduce the issue, on both Edge 103 and Chrome 104 on Windows 10.

Comment: huh, still couldn't reproduce it in the latest version of chrome (104.0.5112.81) in both macos and Windows 10. Here is another gif recording (in windows): https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrR0G.gif

Comment: @CaveJohnson: Ah, you're in Markdown mode. Switch to rich text mode (that's where the issue occurs).

Comment: ah yea, I had it right the first time around but before I knew about putting focus on the editor. I reproduced it. The image is getting duplicated.

Comment: I'm able to reproduce. Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5oSaW.gif, GIF: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5oSaW.gif